For loading 50 million rows of bigquery data into Teradata table, how is teradataml.dataframe.fastload vs. Teradata WriteNOS?
We need to load 50 million rows data from bigquery and load into Teradata table. How do you compare the performances of below two options? Or do you have better ways to handle it?

bigquery data save as PARQUET file by Teradata WriteNOS ==> creating a Teradata table(A) by selecting from an external table(the PARQUET file) ==> insert into destination Teradata table(B) by selecting from A;
bigquery data ==> read into pandas.DataFrame as df ==> teradataml.dataframe.fastload df into destination Teradata table;


It can take a very long time to populate 50 million row pandas dataframe so #2 isn't great. Why so many steps in #1? What about having BigQuery export to Parquet and then using READ_NOS or FOREIGN TABLE in an INSERT/SELECT

Thank you @Fred ok, I will try with option # 1 once I got the TD NOS setup. I will try read_nos directly from Parquet file and insert into final Teradata table.
